# How small are friction bumps?

Tags: energy, kinematics, friction

Friction is a resistance to sliding motion caused by microscopic bumps on surfaces. How small is a "friction bump?" What's the size when an elevation change is no longer considered a hill but is now part of friction?

Comment: As posed, I don't think that there is a right or wrong answer to this, it is model dependent. I would also challenge the "caused by microscopic bumps on surfaces" portion of your definition of friction. This is one potential source of friction but is by no means the exclusive source of friction.

Comment: Firstly, that elevation must be repeated, periodic. A single "bump" will not be considered friction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to come up with a consistent definition of *static* friction for exactly the reason you pointed out: there is something arbitrary in the way we decide what constitutes a deformity on a surface versus what is small enough to be considered a "friction bump" (not that you would find this term in the literature). For example, if you sand a rough piece of wood, you will reduce its coefficient of static friction. Which is the "real" value for the material?

But the bump model of friction does not explain the more important aspects of friction in general, mainly the conversion of velocity into heat. When you drop a baseball into a bucket of sand, both the ball and the sand quickly stop moving. At the same time, the temperature of the sand and the ball rise by enough to exactly account for the loss of kinetic energy. Why does this happen? Fundamentally, the only difference between temperature and speed is that we measure them in different ways. The temperature is really just a measurement of how fast all the little particles are moving that make up the grains of sand.

But then we come across another question which is very similar to the one you asked: how small are the smallest carriers of kinetic energy? At some basic size, matter can't be divided anymore, and so there can't be any friction between things this small. The length scale at which kinetic energy becomes temperature is the *molecular* length scale. The bonds of a water molecule are about an angstrom long ($10^{-10}$ m). Here's a way to interpret that:

Say you took a classroom-variety ruler, and shrunk down to the size of an inch marking on the ruler, and that the ruler itself was shrunk by the same factor as you were. Then say you repeated that process four more times. Then the size of a water molecule, for you, would look to be about the size of a soccer ball [[1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log((1+inch%2F(average+persons+height)),+(size+of+a+water+molecule+%2F+diameter+of+a+soccer+ball)))]. The molecules themselves would not be 'hot' or 'cold', but they would be *fast* or *slow*. In particular, they would all be moving very very fast compared to things in your everyday experience, so you'd better be careful.